# Different color polygons from fusion table in google maps

Tags: google-maps, polygon, google-fusion-tables

I am working with putting polygons, obtained from a fusion table onto a google map. Is there a way to make each polygon have its own unique color based on data from another fusion table, such as iterating through each polygon in my fusionTableLayer? If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically style fusion tables using the Google Maps API v3 [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pl#FusionTablesLayer).  You can create up to [5 styles for one FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer#fusion_table_styles) on a map.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you need to describe what you are trying to do better, to me it meant you could.

Comment: More specifically, each polygon is placed on top of a building and is shaped like that building. I am getting this polygon data from one fusion table and I would like to use another fusion table which contains the color that each polygon should be. Right now this is how I am coloring my polygons which gives them all the same color: `styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: "#00FF00",
    opacity: 0.3
        }
     }]
` and I basically want instead of "#00ff00", a query to the other table that retrieves the color for each of the polygons. Hope that clears it up a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Would the colors need to change?  Or is this just to set there initial color?  You can style (color) polygons defined in a FusionTable using data in a column.  Is that all you need?